# Angular cache not caching

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching

Im using [angular-cache](https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache) library to cache my rest query to browser in AngularJS,

```
angular.module('fbc')
  .service('OrganizationService', function (CacheFactory, $http) {
    // Service logic
    var settings,
    organizationCache, baseURL = "https://api.myapp.com/1";
    if (!CacheFactory.get('organizationCache')) {
      // or CacheFactory('bookCache', { ... });
      CacheFactory.createCache('organizationCache', {
        deleteOnExpire: 'aggressive',
        recycleFreq: 60000
      });
      console.log("No CacheFactory");
    }
    organizationCache = CacheFactory.get('organizationCache');

    settings = {
      cache: organizationCache
    };

    return {
      getAllOrganization: function (promise) {
        return $http.get(baseURL + '/Organization', settings)
          .then(promise);
      }
    };

  });
```

but every time I refresh the browser I can see `No CacheFactory` on my console it means it query every time and not using or their is no cache stored.

Comment: When i put log inside else block no logs it means `!CacheFactory.get('organizationCache')` always `true`.

Answer (score 0):

By default it uses in-memory cache and serves as a replacement for `$cacheFactory` which doesn't support persistent cache.

Check [`storageMode` configuration option](https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache#storagemode) for persistent cache:

> storageMode
>
> Determines the storage medium used by a cache. Default: memory.